# Book recommendation for configuration spaces

Tags: book-recommendation

I once attended to a lecture about configuration spaces, and I loved it because it had a lot of topology. **Is there any good introductory book about configuration spaces?** By the way, I studied Munkres' Topology.

Answer (score 1):

$1-$ Masaaki Yoshida - Hypergeometric Functions, My Love: Modular Interpretations of Configuration Spaces.

$2-$ Edward R. Fadell & Sufian Y. Husseini - Geometry and Topology of Configuration Spaces.

Reference $1$ is more readable, I believe. $:)$

`[Links to illegal copies removed. See edits.]`